# Get DatagridviewComboBoxCell's SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a `Winforms` application which has a `DataGridView`.
The `DataGridView` is not bound to a datasource. I'm reading a text file and according to each line in the file, I'm placing the values of each row to the datagrid.

I have a column in my grid that is a `ComboBoxColumn`. It has a collection of items in it.

My goal is to save to the file the index of the item that is displayed in the cell.
However, it seems that `ComboBoxCell` doesn't have the `SelectedIndex` property like `ComboBox`.

It is important to mention that I need to know the index of the item displayed only when the user hits "Save" option, So I don't believe that editingControlShowing event is my way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you got it almost right: In order to find the **chosen index** you **do** need to code the `EditingControlShowing` event, just make sure to keep a reference to the `ComboBox` that is used during the edit:

```
  // hook up the event somwhere:
   dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

 // keep a reference to the editing comtrol:
 ComboBox combo = null;

 // fill the reference, once it is valid:
 void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
 {
     combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
 }
```

Now you can use it:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int index = -1;
        if (combo != null) index = combo.SelectedIndex;
        // now do what you want..
}
```

**Note** that this is just a minimal example. If your users will edit several columns and rows before they press the  'Save' Buton, you will need to store either the `ComboBoxes`, or, less expensive, the `SelectedIndex`, maybe in the `CellEndEdit` event on a per Cell basis. The Cells' `Tag` are obvious storage places:

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (combo != null) 
       dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Tag = combo.SelectedIndex;
}
```

In this version you will obviously retrieve the index from the `Tag`, not from combo..

Of course you could also find an `Item` from the `Value` like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dcc = 
                        (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1[yourColumn, yourRow];
int index = dcc.Items.IndexOf(dcc.Value);
```

But that will simply get the **first** fitting index, not the one that was actually chosen..

Comment: The Tag property combined with those events gave me the solution I needed. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
int cmbindex =0;
for(int i=0;i<datagridview1;i++)
{
cmbindex = convert.toint32(datagridview1["cmbboxcellname",i].value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `.Value` of `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` and then find index of it.

```js
DataGridViewComboBoxCell Cell = Your_Cell_Here;
int index = Cell.Items.Cast<object>().ToList().IndexOf(Cell.SelectedItem);
```